# expand page element in a modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-directive-link

I have a widget in the page that shows google chart for some data with couple of filters to filter the chart data and with a print icon to print it.

I want to add a button to open this same widget with the chart, filters and print functionality working in a modal with a larger screen view. because the widget is small in the page.

I have tried to add a button, and added a function for this button in the link function to open `element.html()` in a modal, the html worked but the issue is that the filters and the print are not functional .

What's wrong with `element.html()` ? I have tired to use $compile but it got me into many errors. what can I use?

```
app.directive("widget", function ($rootScope) {
        return {
                restrict: "EA",
                scope: { 
                        title: '=',
                        options: '='
                },
                transclude: true,
                templateUrl: "widget.html",
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
                    scope.print = function() {....}
                    scope.filterChart = function() {....}

                    scope.expand = function() {
                      $rootScope.openModal("expand Modal", element.html(), {});      
                    } 
                }
        }
```

note that $rootScope.openModal is just a wrapper service that uses the $modal service, takes a title and a body

Comment: @MaximShoustin done

Comment: We can't tell what is wrong with your use of `element.html()` when you don't include that code. In general  AngularJS directives need to be compiled with the $compile service. They will not work if simply added with `element.html()`. If you get errors using the $compile service, we need to see that code and the complete text of those error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think we  have some issue with design.

To sort things out:

You have some logic (in your case "widget with the chart, filters and print functionality")

This logic should be implemented in `directive` or `component` (1.5+).

So directive name is `widget` like you did.

This directive you can implement in main page (what you did so far) or as part of modal. The modal is wrapper only for your `widget`. So create new emplty modal, put inside `<widget title="xx" options=someOptions></widget>` on you are fine

---

Since you have isolate scope directive I don't see any problem to make it work.

Comment: the problem is that the filters are not functioning, so after the modal opens if I add console.log inside the filter function, or the print function , and click on those from inside the modal .. nothing happens

Comment: Every modal has his own scope, so check if scope is updated